# High power equvalient for a zener

Tags: design, zener, high-power

Sometimes the power rating of a simple zener diode is not enough for some works, but their precious ability is needed.

What to do?

put two zeners in series? I heard that it will work in theory but in reality the break down voltages of the them will not be equal. so the mixture will not work as desired.

What is the solution?

Comment: For which purpose? Zener diodes have different applications.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to put it in a circuit to make a steady voltage. to make the voltage smooth.

Comment: You probably want a proper voltage regulator, or a full DC-DC converter. Bare Zeners are only useful in small circuits. If you want a precise value, special ICs are available for that as well.

Comment: yes. but there is no 60V linear regulator for example. but there are 60V zeners.

Comment: You could build one from discrete components. What exactly is your power requirement? Wasting a lot of energy in Zeners (or even linear regulators) is seldom a good idea.

Comment: @BlueSky Are you sure? Have you dug the websites of some distributors ? like Mouser? e.g. http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Power-Management-ICs/Linear-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-5cg9g/ or http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Power-Management-ICs/Voltage-Regulators-Switching-Regulators/_/N-668jt/

Comment: "Sometimes the power rating of a simple zener diode is not enough for some works" Yes and that's why there are some components that make desired output for your job. Buck ICs or DC-DC converters or etc.

Comment: @roh I told you. DC converters are not for high voltages like 60 or near that. or there are large. a simple zener does the regulation itself without need of much space.

Comment: But that's way off! and you didn't say that you need small circuit(or you have small space or something like that). "or there are large" What do you mean? it doesn't make any sense to me. you mean they occupy a big space?

Comment: @roh. you are right. but I said equivalent for zener. what size is a zener? usually small. isn't it?

Comment: AND also there are some regulators that can handle this voltage range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30311/discussion-between-roh-and-bluesky).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two zener diodes in series will work in practice too. But usually that would be used to create a higher voltage zener, rather than a higher power.

You can use a zener diode in conjunction with a transistor to provide a high power shunt:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fL8PuI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is that resistor and why is it there? and how to calculate the resistance?

Comment: Calculate the resistor to drop 0.6V for the zener current at the desired voltage.

Comment: Its not critical, the circuit will work without it, it just increases the current through the Zener so that the load will be shared between the transistor and Zener. calculate it (roughly) by assuming the voltage across it will be 0.7V and using the max current your Zener can take at the max input voltage you intend to apply to the circuit.

Comment: That last bit of advice doesn't make any sense. The "max input voltage" is fixed at Vz + Vbe. What you really need to know is the maximum current you want the circuit to handle. Assuming the transistor has a beta of 50, 98% of the current will be passing through the transistor, and 2% will be passing through the zener. You then select the resistor so that it also passes 2% of the current when the voltage across it is Vbe (0.7 volts), which insures that the zener current never varies by more than a 2:1 range.

Comment: ... If you want even tighter control, use a smaller resistor, but make sure that the total current through the zener doesn't exceed its ratings.

Comment: @DaveTweed just tell me if I am true: I subtract 0.7 from the zener voltage. then divide the result by the maximum zener current. the final number will be the resistance of R1. am I right?

Comment: No, subtract the maximum base current of the transistor from the maximum zener current, then divide 0.7 volts by that number. For example, suppose you have a 400 mW, 12 V zener. The maximum zener current is 400 mW / 12 V = 33.3 mA. Let's say you want the transistor to handle 1A, and its beta is 50, so it needs up to 1 A / 50 = 20 mA of base current. Therefore, the resistor current will be 33.3 mA - 20 mA = 13.3 mA, and its value should be 0.7 V / 13.3 mA = 52.6 ohms. The next larger standard value would be 56 ohms.

Comment: @DaveTweed so in your example the circuit will work as a 11.3V zener? or as a 12V zener?

Comment: As a 12.7 V zener. As I said before, you add the Vbe of the transistor to the actual zener voltage.